# CNContact new predicate methods missing

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cncontactstore

I am using the CNContactStore with predicateForContacts(matchingName:). I need the other two new type methods to be implemented. I see that the below methods

```
predicateForContacts(matching:), predicateForContacts(matchingEmailAddress:)
```

when added don't compile and are not found in the framework. Can anyone help with how can I get this thing working?

Comment: They are new to Xcode 10 in iOS 12.

Comment: But I see the documentation says its available for iOS 11+?

Comment: It does. That's odd. In Xcode 9 (iOS 11), those methods were not in the headers and they were not documented. In Xcode 10, the methods have been added but they are marked as available since iOS 11. They must have existed in iOS 11 but were private and now they are public.

Comment: Sorry this is not related to the question but, does Xcode 9.4.1 getting an incremental update sometime around or I have to manually move to XCode 10?

Comment: At this moment, Xcode 10GM is available on developer.apple.com. It should be a normal update in the Mac App Store sometime next week.

Comment: Thanks for the info and taking time. @rmaddy